# Powershell unable to open input file for Sybase isql

Tags: powershell, sybase

I am trying to make a Sybase isql call from Powershell. The SQL file is a simple "select count" for now. It works from a standard command prompt but fails in Powershell.

Command Prompt:

```
H:\>isql -SSomeServer -USomeUser -PSomePassword -DSomeDatabase -i\\path\to\sql\file\SomeFile.sql

 -----------
        81210

(1 row affected)
```

Powershell:

```
PS H:\> isql -SSomeServer -USomeUser -PSomePassword -DSomeDatabase -i\\path\to\sql\file\SomeFile.sql
 Unable to open input file '\\path\to\sql\file\SomeFile'.
```

I have tried putting single and double quotes around the file, but that results in a continued prompt (>>).

Does anyone know why this fails?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to wrap the entire last parameter with single-quotes:

`isql -SSomeServer -USomeUser -PSomePassword -DSomeDatabase '-i\\path\to\sql\file\SomeFile.sql'`

Answer (score 0):

You need to put quotes around the -i switch: -i"\path\to\sql\file\SomeFile.sql"